# .htaccess mod_rewrite add "/" to the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteBase /kajak/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^moduli/([^/]+)/(.*)$ moduli/$1/index.php/$2 [L]
```

Now `/` is appended to every URL. For example, `http://127.0.0.1/moduli/novice` becomes `http://127.0.0.1/moduli/novice/`.

How can I prevent getting `/` at the end?

Comment: Either please explain what you would like to do in a more thought out way (perhaps expanding upon how your RewriteBase is /kajak/ and yet /kajak/ is not present in your example URLs) or select an answer below as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know the answer to your question, I will note two oddities about your question and your code that may be related to the problem at hand.

1. With the RewriteBase you have in your code, those rules should not even be being triggered.
2. While I am new to regex myself, I look at ([^/]+) and am a little confused as to why you are capturing it.  I know that ^ matches the START of the string, which would never be true since you already have another one at the real start of the string.

This being said, I would probably write the code as below:

```
RewriteBase /moduli/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1/index.php/$2 [L]
```

This would rewrite URLs as below:

```
http://www.website.com/moduli/novice/view
http://www.website.com/moduli/novice/index.php/view
```

Based on your block of code, this seems to be what you are trying to do.  If it is not, then I am sorry.

Comment: thx for your answer. You code is better and works fine but have the same problem. Still add "/" ad the end of the url.

Comment: You are welcome.  If my answer was the answer to your question, please mark is as such.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's related to your rewrite rule, (it does not match it).

The / is added because when you request `http://example.com/xx/zz` and the web server detects `zz` is a directory, it transforms it to `http://example.com/xx/zz/` through a 301 redirect (the browser makes another request - check you apache logs).

Read about the *trailing slash redirect* thing [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html).

The, you must aks yourself, what do you want to happen when the url requested is `http://127.0.0.1/moduli/novice/` (Do you want it to be be catched by your redirect or not? Currently it's not catched because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`)

BTW, I don't quite understand your `RewriteBase /kajak/` line there - are you sure it's correct?

Comment: it is correct becouse folder is kajak. But i chage code as cbroughton suggest. Yes i want to be cached by redirect